# Approval Process: Totally approve by approver 2 if approver 1 does not approve after 2 days

Tags: apex, approval-process, approval-step, approve-action

I dont know if this is possible.
I want to create a workflow of 2 approvers(step by step wherein approver2 can only approve if approver 1 already approved) however, if approver 1 did not approve it after 2 days, approver 2 can approve. Is this possible? thanks

Comment: up.......................